# How Odoo can get Json data which is generated by php file in other server?

Tags: php, json, web-services, odoo

There is a [php](/questions/tagged/php) file in a server that generate data in [json](/questions/tagged/json) Format.

In the other server, 
[odoo](/questions/tagged/odoo) need to get those data from that [php](/questions/tagged/php) file, 
and then [odoo](/questions/tagged/odoo) display it.

How could I do this case ?
I know this use web service feature concept,
but I still have no idea how to implement it to [odoo](/questions/tagged/odoo).
such where I have to put the script that calling that [php](/questions/tagged/php) file containing [json](/questions/tagged/json) format in the other server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an HTTP request on the remote server to download the json document. You can use the `urllib2` module from Python's standard library for this (https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html)

If you don't want the data to appear as raw json in Odoo, you will probably need to parse the json document. You can use the `json` module from Python's standard library for this (https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html?highlight=json#module-json). Then you can store the parsed data in an suitable Odoo Model.

On the other hand, if the raw json is fine, you can just store it in any `fields.Text` field of an Odoo model.